# OpenVPN disabling DH

Tags: openvpn

I'm reading [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) on how to setup and configure an OpenVPN server. I noticed something which I've not seen anywhere else:

```
;dh dh2048.pem
dh none
```

Why DH is disabled? What are the pros and cons?

In case it matters here's the rest of the configuration related to cryptography:

```
tls-crypt ta.key
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They answer it right in the guide:

> Next, find the line containing a dh directive, which defines Diffie-Hellman parameters. **Since we’ve configured all the certificates to use Elliptic Curve Cryptography, there is no need for a Diffie-Hellman seed file**.

OpenVPN's manual says something similar:

> --dh file
> File containing Diffie Hellman parameters in .pem format (required for --tls-server only).Set file=none to disable Diffie Hellman key exchange (and use ECDH only). Note that this requires peers to be using an SSL library that supports ECDH TLS cipher suites (e.g. OpenSSL 1.0.1+, or mbed TLS 2.0+).

For the type of certificates that guide is telling you to use, the Diffie-Hellman parameters aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't know what happens if I don't disable it. I'm trying to understand the rationale and didn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: @OmidShojaee if you don't disable it, it won't be used anyways, assuming you are generating the certificates as the guide recommends.